# Optimize and delete images in WordPress

Tags: plugins, images

I've uploaded several images to my blog posts. I didn't cared about their size so I've put there even 5mb images which could be easily compressed for 200kb. 
I know that wordpress already processed them, cutted and customized, but now I'm worried as my whole blog is very big.

I would like to delete originals or at least replace them with compressed copies.

Can I do it manually, download, delete, compress and upload with the same name ?

or

Is there any simple plugin which will do the same for me ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

for regenerate all images and you should create required size in theme using:

```
function custom_thumbs() {
    add_image_size( 'cover-size', 1600, 450, true ); 
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_thumbs' );
```

you can use optimized image using :

```
$attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); 
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'cover-size' ); 
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'cover-size' );
```

Above function help you to load page very fast in browser and it will not load original image.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the "[EWWW Image Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/)" plugin will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I have a chance to write a small wrapper that basically implements such functionality...

1. I was thinking about when I should run my optimization and what exactly I should process files. Ended up in next conclusions...

   1. The main Image will be changed somewhere later, using wp_cron schedule. Nothing particularly interesting... you taking your file, run it through the optimisation pipeline, and in case `Success` setting param to not optimize it again in post meta, in case of `fail` mark it as `Failed` and forget about image.
   2. With copies it was easier. I just use `wp_update_attachment_metadata` filter $hook to get files list when update metadata was triggered (on image size generation for example).

```

```
add_filter( 'wp_update_attachment_metadata', 
    array( __CLASS__, 'optimize_images_in_foreach' ), 100, 2 );

Files Optimization.
/**
 * Optimize Copies of imges in loop while images regeneration
 *
 * @param  array  $metadata      Image Metadata (images, exif data, etc...)
 * @param  int    $attachment_id Attachment id
 * @return array
 */
function optimize_images_in_foreach( $metadata, $attachment_id ) {
    $original_file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
    if ( ! empty( $metadata['sizes'] ) && is_array( $metadata['sizes'] ) ) {
       foreach( $metadata['sizes'] as $size => $item )
          do_action( 'optimize_image', 
            str_replace( basename( $original_file ), $item['file'], $original_file ) );
        }
    }    
    return $metadata;
}
```

```

2. As you see I have just run own action for images... `optimize_image`. On first stage it was just wrapper for `pngout` and `jpegtran`, later it was a bit harder implementation with advanced cron schedules and Kraken service (image optimization).

```

```
/**
 * Run Image Optimization to Jpeg's and PNG's

 * @param  string $image IMage Location in filesystem
 * @return void
 */
function optimize_images_in_foreach_jpeg_png_optimization( $image ) {
    $extension = array_pop(explode( '.', basename( $image ) ) );

    // `images_optimization` is global option that holds a cli command for image optimization
    //  examples...
    // 'png'  => /opt/local/bin/optipng = '{$image}', 
    // 'jpeg' => /opt/local/bin/jpegtran -copy none -maxmemory 256Mb  -optimize \
    //                                          -outfile '{$image}' '{$image}'

    $optimization = get_site_option('images_optimization');

    if ( in_array($extension, array( 'jpeg', 'jpg' ) ) ) {
        $type = 'jpeg';
    } elseif ( in_array( $extension, array( 'png' ) ) ) {
        $type = 'png';
    } else {
        $type = 'default';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $optimization[ $type ] ) ) {
        $optimization[$type] = str_replace( '{$image}', $image, $optimization[ $type ] ); 
        // execute is a pipline to exec in this itteration.
        execute( "{$optimization[$type]}" );
    }   
}
```

```

P.S.
I beg a pardon for a code formatting... it's failing to work without "```"